# Can a @NonNull annotated http request object field in springboot be accessed in the setter methods, and operated upon, without throwing null pointer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

The following is a HTTP request object, and it captures the json input from the user to the SpringBoot Application.

```
package com.bablo.google.request;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class SomeRequest implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    private Long userId;

    private String resNote; //this is not annotated with @NotNull
    @NotNull
    private String revTag;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(final Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getResNote() {
        return responseNote;
    }

    public void setResNote(final String resNote) {
        this.resNote = resNote.trim();    //Call to trim() method of the String object.
    }

    public String getRevTag() {
        return revTag;
    }

    public void setRevTag(final String revTag) {
        this.revTag = revTag.trim();     //Call to the trim() method of the String object.
    }

}
```

Can a string field of a class with @NotNull validated annotation be trimmed in the setter methods?

Here the revTag field is annotated with @NotNull and is being trimmed in the setter methods, in this situation if the incoming request object is have null as revTag value, will it be throwing NullPointerException?
What will happen in this case?

resNote field is not annotated with @NotNull, and if the null value comes for resNote this will throw NullPointerException for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can safely trim in setter method as binding to object itself would fail if revTag value is not present in the request.

**Note:** @Valid annotation should be added in your request handling method in your controller to enabling data binding validation.

Below Controller & JUnit proves the same.

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/demo/req")
    public ResponseEntity handleSomeGetRequest(@Valid SomeRequest someRequest){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("success");
    }
}


@WebMvcTest(value = DemoController.class)
class DemoControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testNotNullValidation() throws Exception {

        //invoking the endpoint without any request param and this throws BadRequest
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/demo/req"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }

}

Error in the log trace. 
2020-05-19 22:34:18.509  WARN 9276 --- [    Test worker] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'someRequest' on field 'userId': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.someRequest.userId,NotNull.userId,NotNull.java.lang.Long,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [someRequest.userId,userId]; arguments []; default message [userId]]; default message [must not be null]
Field error in object 'someRequest' on field 'revTag': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.someRequest.revTag,NotNull.revTag,NotNull.java.lang.String,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [someRequest.revTag,revTag]; arguments []; default message [revTag]]; default message [must not be null]]
```

Comment: How you wrote this @WebMvcTest method, please kindly elaborate more on this, please tell or point to resource where we get information to set up this thing.

Comment: @WebMvcTest is provided by spring boot test framework to test Controllers in isolation. Basically it loads only the beans required to test the web layer. Hope this link provides more clarification. https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-web-controller-test

Comment: Can you also please throw some more light on this @Valid annotation that you mentioned. This is part of javax.validation.* package correct!!

Comment: Yes. This annotation enables validation of request params and path variables during data binding

Comment: Check this link for more info. https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

Since a certain version of Hibernate, there is available [method level validation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_method_validation) and the annotation can be placed among formal parameters of the method:

```
@NotNull
private Long userId;

private String resNote;

...

public String setResNote(@NotNull final String resNote) {
    this.resNote = resNote.trim()
}
```

Comment: Actually my question has changed a little, I mean I am now more clearly expressing the doubt that I have, would you like to edit the answer that you gave.